# In the following code, where is cx and cy defined?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, methods

I have the following code, and it works. It draws a little face in the applet window. It was for an assignment that I didn't really understand so I had to copy a lot of it. I'm understanding most of it now except where does cx and cy get defined? Or does the line

```
addFace(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
```

define it by plugging the two variables (x,y) into the other methods that also have two variables in their methods. I guess my question is. When you have something in the parenthesis of a method does that something then get plugged into any other method you call as long as it has the same about of something? Example:

If I had

```
funTimes(48, 98 / 3, 3 + 5);
```

and then called

```
funTimes(x,y,z);{
    int i = x + y - z;
    println(i);
}
```

later in the code, would x,y,z take on the values of the three other integers?

Below is the code in question. Thanks a bunch!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class robotface extends GraphicsProgram{

/*setting values for dimensions */
    private static final int HEAD_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int HEAD_HEIGHT = 150;
    private static final int EYE_RADIUS = 10;
    private static final int MOUTH_WIDTH = 60;
    private static final int MOUTH_HEIGHT = 20;

    public void run(){
        addFace(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    }

        private void addFace(double cx, double cy){
            addHead(cx,cy);
            addEye(cx - HEAD_WIDTH / 4, cy - HEAD_HEIGHT / 4);
            addEye(cx + HEAD_WIDTH / 4, cy - HEAD_HEIGHT / 4);
            addMouth(cx, cy + HEAD_HEIGHT / 4);
        }
        private void addHead(double cx, double cy){ 
            double x = cx - HEAD_WIDTH / 2;
            double y = cy - HEAD_HEIGHT / 2;    
            GRect head = new GRect(x,y,HEAD_WIDTH,HEAD_HEIGHT);
            head.setFilled(true);
            head.setFillColor(Color.GRAY);      
            add(head);
        }

        private void addEye(double cx, double cy){  
            double x = cx - EYE_RADIUS;
            double y = cy - EYE_RADIUS; 
            GOval eye = new GOval(x,y,EYE_RADIUS*2,EYE_RADIUS*2);
            eye.setFilled(true);
            eye.setFillColor(Color.YELLOW);
            eye.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            add(eye);
        }
        private void addMouth(double cx, double cy){    
            double x = cx - MOUTH_WIDTH / 2;
            double y = cy - MOUTH_HEIGHT / 2;
            GRect mouth = new GRect(x,y,MOUTH_WIDTH,MOUTH_HEIGHT);
            mouth.setFilled(true);
            mouth.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            mouth.setFillColor(Color.WHITE);
            add(mouth);
        }




    }
```

Comment: In the method signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually these two are the temporary variables defined at the time of function definition of type double :

```
 private void addFace(double cx, double cy)
```

For performing operations in that methods. you also can use another names for those variables. 
`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are the inbuilt functions for getting `width` and `height` of window.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass in parameters there are automatically defined. E.g.

```
public static void callFoo() {
    foo(10, 10);
}

public static void foo(int bar1, int bar2) {
    //Do something.
    System.out.println(bar1 + bar2);
}
```

In this example when foo() is called it gives it two `int` parameters. Inside the foo() method bar1 and bar2 are automatically defined with whatever was passed in.

Also please note that bar1 and bar2 are not able to be used after the method is finished executing. This is because they are stored in the stack.